# Cordova: Displaying camera in hybrid app causes screen dimension to get squashed

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, camera

Cordova version:

```
6.1.1
```

Installed Plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
```

Installed Platforms:

```
ios 4.1.1
```

I am running a Cordova app built using the above version of the tooling on an iPod with iOS Version 9.3.1 installed.

When opening the Camera via the plugin, you see the screen visibly squash up horizontally before the camera is displayed. When closing the camera, the screen remains squashed, and the only way to recover is to change the orientation, which then allows the screen to expand out again. I checked the widths of all the screen elements, and they all look correct (320px wide) apart from document.documentElement.clientWidth (which returns 70px).

I am unsure as to what is causing this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update:**

This seems to be down to an issue with the StatusBar plugin. If you remove this plugin from the project, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the StatusBar plugin as @ISeeBinary mentioned. 
However, if you still want to keep the StatusBar plugin you can use the 2.0.0 version which does not have this issue,

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.0.0
```